# Python notify main code when variable change in another .py file

Tags: python

I can't wrap my head around how to accomplish the following scenario:

On my main.py and request.py i have a reference to a config.py witch contains some configuration variables.
In this sample an offline variable that are either True or False.

What I would like to do is:
If eg. in my request.py I set the config.offline = True, then I would like to do somethin on my main.py.

But main.py also references the request.py so I cannot call any functions from request.py..

Any ideas to how I can do this?

I have over 1000 lines of code, so I cannot show every thing, but i have tried to show the most important:

main.py:

```
import config as cfg
import request as req

def doStuffWhenOfflineVarChanges(newState):
  print(newState)
```

config.py:

```
offline = True
```

request.py:

```
import config as cfg

def logEntrance(barCode, noOfGuests, dt=datetime.now()):
    date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    time = dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': cfg.auth}

    url = 'https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/' + cfg.customerId + '/api.ashx'
    params = {"inputtype": "logentrances"}
    pl = [{"Barcode": barCode ,  "PoeID": cfg.poeId,  "UserID": cfg.userId,  "EntranceDate": date,  "EntranceTime": time,  "NoOfGuests": str(noOfGuests),  "OfflineMode": cfg.offline}]

    #print(url)
    print(pl)

    try:
        r = requests.post(url, json=pl, params=params, headers=headers)

        print(r.status_code)
    except:
        cfg.offline = True
    return r
```

Comment: "main.py also references the request.py so I cannot call any functions from request.py": huh, why? What limits calling request functions?

Comment: Please add what you have already done in terms of code. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: are you trying to change variables at runtime?

Comment: @9769953
I have updated the question with some code samples

Comment: @VandanRevanur 
I have updated the question with some code samples

Answer (score 0):

You need a call back function to handle the change in your onfig.py file!

```
# config.py
offline = False

def doStuffWhenOfflineVarChanges(newState):
    print(newState)

# request.py
import config as cfg

class OfflineState:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self._callback = callback
        self._offline = cfg.offline
    
    @property
    def offline(self):
        return self._offline
    
    @offline.setter
    def offline(self, value):
        self._offline = value
        self._callback(value)

offline_state = OfflineState(cfg.doStuffWhenOfflineVarChanges)

import requests
import datetime

def logEntrance(barCode, noOfGuests, dt=datetime.now()):
    date = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    time = dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': cfg.auth}

    url = 'https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/' + cfg.customerId + '/api.ashx'
    params = {"inputtype": "logentrances"}
    pl = [{"Barcode": barCode ,  "PoeID": cfg.poeId,  "UserID": cfg.userId,  "EntranceDate": date,  "EntranceTime": time,  "NoOfGuests": str(noOfGuests),  "OfflineMode": offline_state.offline}]

    try:
        r = requests.post(url, json=pl, params=params, headers=headers)
    except:
        offline_state.offline = True
    return r
```

Comment: I'm not sure i follow... the doStuffWhenOfflineVarChanges are in my main.py, and the class OfflineState should be in my config.py?

Comment: @Jesper Sorry I just realized what you wanted from the title! I've updated my answer so it goes with your needs!